# How to map a key in a command line argument inside a key mapping?

Tags: vim

The naive approach

`nnoremap <leader>s :!echo "foo" <bar> vim -c="nnoremap x :q<cr>" -<cr>`

displays errors. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's a general application question, with an example shown as a kind of `more`. Are there really no escape sequences for this?

Comment: The title of your post is a question my tiny brain can't parse, and the body is an example of what _isn't_ an answer to your unparseable question. :) That's a good start already (filtering out people with cognitive deficiencies and the like), :) but maybe you could start anew?  Perhaps by explaining what are you trying to achieve, in what context would that be useful, and what problem did you encounter trying to make it work?

Comment: Sure, here's a more detailed explanation of the example: when running shell commands, I usually like neither less nor more nor most. I prefer to use vim as my stdout paginator. If I'm editing in vim and I need to run a shell command, instead of running it through more, I want to use another, "throw-away" temporary instance of vim to page the output. Since I'm using vim, I want to use the power of vim, including mapping of keys, which is what the command above does. It's just a simple 2nd level recursion, all of us programmers are intimately familiar with, but in a different context :)

Comment: Well I'm not a programmer, which is why my first try would be something like this: `alias more='view -u ~/.vim/view_profile'`.  You'd then customise Vim-as-a-viewer to your heart's content by adding options to ` ~/.vim/view_profile`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that seems like it might be a good solution also. I use vim-scanvenger and the recursive way seems more customizable for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There are two problems with my original code. The first being an equals sign after `-c`. For the other, the solution is to use `<lt>cr>` instead of `<cr>`. So the entire command would look like this:

`nnoremap <leader>s :!echo "foo" <bar> vim -c "nnoremap x :q<lt>cr>" -<cr>`

`:help <lt>`